# Violation of Primary Key constraint when Inserting

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with a primary key made up from 4 columns like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INV_STOCK_TEST]
(
    [STOCK_WRH_ID]  [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [STOCK_LOC_ID]  [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [STOCK_ITEM_NO] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [STOCK_BEG_QTY] [decimal](9, 2) NULL,
    [YEAR]          [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [PK__INV_STOC__3B64B7082B9540B9]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (
        [STOCK_WRH_ID] ASC,
        [STOCK_LOC_ID] ASC,
        [STOCK_ITEM_NO] ASC,
        [YEAR] ASC
    )WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I have a procedure to update yearly data in this table

```
DECLARE @YEAR nvarchar(20)

SET @YEAR = (SELECT TOP 1 [YEAR] FROM INV_STOCK_TEST ORDER BY [YEAR] DESC)

INSERT INTO INV_STOCK_TEST([STOCK_WRH_ID], [YEAR],
                           [STOCK_LOC_ID], [STOCK_BEG_QTY], [STOCK_ITEM_NO])
    SELECT
        STOCK_WRH_ID, @YEAR + 1,
        STOCK_LOC_ID, 0, STOCK_ITEM_NO
    FROM
        INV_STOCK_TEST
```

Sample inserted data

```
A   A   ITEM_A  0.00    2014
A   A   ITEM_A  0.00    2015
B   B   ITEM_B  0.00    2014
B   B   ITEM_B  0.00    2015
```

It's okay when year 2014 to 2015 but when 2015 to 2016 and I run the procedure, I get this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__INV_STOC__3B64B7082B9540B9'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.INV_STOCK_TEST'. The
>   duplicate key value is (A, A, ITEM_A, 2017).

I cannot change the primary key, how to fix this?

Comment: Primary keys cannot have duplicate data. you might have to redesign the table if u want such values to be inserted. Use this code to drop the primary key "ALTER TABLE INV_STOCK_TEST
DROP CONSTRAINT PK__INV_STOC__3B64B7082B9540B9"

Comment: i need keep data not duplicate, i insert data with 3 same primary data inserted and 1 primary data different (YEAR)

Answer (score 0):

Have an ID field that is related to the record and use that as a primary key, instead of trying to make multiple non-unique identifying fields.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INV_STOCK_TEST]
(
[PK_ID]         [INT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[STOCK_WRH_ID]  [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[STOCK_LOC_ID]  [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[STOCK_ITEM_NO] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[STOCK_BEG_QTY] [int] NULL, -- decimals lack precision
                            -- use integers when dealing with discrete.
[YEAR]          [varchar](5) NOT NULL --I would use a datetime here
                                      --purely for formatting reasons
)
```

the procedure should work exactly the same.

Comment: yes it should work but it not prevent duplicated same item same wrh ,same loc, same year, and that's become problem